# How can I get the error response body in Nuxt 3 using useFetch?

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have a /services/userService.js file in Nuxt 3:

```
const baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080/api/auth/'
const headers = {
  Accept: 'application/json',
  'Content-type': 'application/json',
}

export default {
  signinNewUser(firstName, secondName, email, password) {
    return useFetch('/signup', {
      method: 'POST',
      baseURL: baseURL,
      headers: headers,
      body: {
        firstName,
        secondName,
        email,
        password,
      },
    })
  },
}
```

And I have the following function in /store/user.js

```
async registerUser(firstName, secondName, email, password) {
      return userService
        .signinNewUser(firstName, secondName, email, password)
        .then(
          (res) => {
            const data = res.data.value
            const error = res.error.value
            if (error) {
              console.log(error)
            } else {
              this.registered = true
            }
          },
          (error) => {
            console.log('exception...')
            console.log(error)
          }
        )
    },
```

My auth API can answer with a 400 status code and different error messages in the response body like:

```
{"message":"Error: Email is already in use!"}
{"message":"Error: FirstName is already in use!"}
```

etc...

I want to be able to access those messages in order to show to the user different error messages so he/she knows how to fix the issue.

How can I achieve that?

I tried accessing the error object but it doesn't contain a reference to the response body, data object is null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the body of the error response using the `data` key from the error reference object. An http error will not always raise an error in the composable.

```js
const data = error.value.data;
```

```js
async registerUser(firstName, secondName, email, password) {
      return userService
        .signinNewUser(firstName, secondName, email, password)
        .then(
          (res) => {
            const data = res.data.value
            const error = res.error.value
            if (error) {
              console.log(error)
              this.error = error.data; // <== To handle the error data.
            } else {
              this.registered = true
            }
          },
          (error) => {
            console.log('exception...')
            console.log(error)
          }
        )
    },
```

Also, the `useFetch` composable allows you to use `interceptors` to access the data in an other fashion, please refer to the [documentation on the subject](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch#example).